# Determing object location in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I've been learning Unity 3D, slowly. I'm trying to make a maze, and need an event to occur when they reach the finish area.

How do I fetch object location and check if it's in the target area? Using Javascript.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your end area can be treated as a box, you could add a BoxCollider to your scene around the finish area and set its `isTrigger` property to true. Then you'll get a callback to `OnTriggerEnter` on your entity when it enters the area, which you can subsequently use to end the level or whatever.

Comment: +1 - building with less code and more logical organization using the editor always makes more sense. Use code in unity to express what you can't with their world building tools alone.

Answer (score 2):

As Peter G [states on Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/26856/check-object-for-motion.html):

> If you have a rigidbody, then you can do Rigidbody.IsSleeping() to
>   check if your rigidbody is sleeping
>
> If you are using a Character Controller, then checking to see if
>   CharacterController.velocity == Vector3.zero;
>
> Or, you can manually save a Vector3 every frame that remembers the
>   last position. Something like:

```
function Update () {
 curPos = position;
 if(curPos == lastPos) {
     print("Not moving");
 }
 lastPos = curPos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you by target area you mean the finish area then 
you can do this in several ways

you can use collides

in a simple way : 
(1) create a plane , create a tag named "finish" 
(2) then select the player then click the dropdown "tag" in the inspector . search for "finish" and select it .
you will also need to add a collider to your gameobject.

then create a new JavaScript and add this code to it

```
    function OnCollisionEnter(collision : Collision){
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "finish"){ 

//"STOP GAMEOBJECT FROM MOVING"
}

}
```

or use this method

place this script on your player .
this script is probably just as god as using colliders for what you are doing

```
 var other : Transform;
    function Update ()
    {

    var dist = Vector3.Distance(other.position, transform.position);

    if (dist < 100)
    {
    //stop player movent here 
// move player to exact finish position over time 

    }

    }
```